# ¿Como saber que cilentes ha comprado mas productos? SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo estas tablas

Ventas:

```
CREATE TABLE `ventas` (
  `id_venta` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_usuario` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fecha` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `ventas` (`id_venta`, `id_usuario`, `fecha`) VALUES
(1, 2, '2020-04-25 06:33:56'),
(2, 2, '2020-03-21 15:33:56'),
(3, 2, '2020-02-28 15:33:56'),
(4, 3, '2020-02-03 15:33:56'),
(5, 3, '2020-01-07 15:33:56'),
(6, 4, '2020-05-25 15:33:56'),
(7, 4, '2020-04-27 15:33:56'),
(8, 5, '2020-03-16 15:33:56'),
(9, 5, '2017-12-05 15:33:56'),
(10, 6, '2020-01-15 15:33:56'),
(11, 7, '2019-11-09 15:33:56'),
(12, 7, '2019-10-05 15:33:56'),
(13, 7, '2020-05-12 15:33:56'),
(14, 7, '2020-01-28 15:33:56'),
(15, 8, '2020-03-01 15:33:56'),
(16, 9, '2020-04-17 15:33:56'),
(17, 10, '2020-02-09 15:33:56'),
(18, 11, '2019-11-05 15:33:56'),
(19, 11, '2020-02-12 15:33:56'),
(20, 11, '2020-03-21 15:33:56'),
(21, 11, '2020-03-21 15:33:56'),
(22, 11, '2020-04-26 15:33:56'),
(23, 1, '2020-05-05 15:33:56'),
(24, 2, '2020-05-05 21:40:58');
```

Detalle ventas:

```
CREATE TABLE `detalle_ventas` (
  `id_venta` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_producto` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `precio` double NOT NULL,
  `cantidad` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `detalle_ventas` (`id_venta`, `id_producto`, `precio`, `cantidad`) VALUES
(1, 2, 18000.9, 1),
(1, 4, 4898.99, 1),
(1, 1, 40000, 2),
(2, 3, 25000, 1),
(3, 4, 4898.99, 1),
(4, 6, 12000, 1),
(4, 8, 7000, 2),
(4, 11, 5400, 1),
(5, 14, 560, 1),
(6, 10, 2300.56, 3),
(6, 13, 230, 2),
(6, 12, 300, 1),
(7, 16, 17000, 1),
(8, 4, 4898.99, 3),
(8, 1, 40000, 3),
(8, 9, 1000, 1),
(8, 10, 2300.56, 2),
(8, 15, 430, 2),
(9, 3, 25000, 1),
(10, 3, 25000, 4),
(11, 6, 12000, 2),
(12, 1, 40000, 1),
(13, 14, 560, 1),
(14, 4, 4898.99, 5),
(15, 7, 3000, 3),
(15, 9, 1000, 1),
(15, 13, 230, 1),
(15, 11, 5400, 1),
(15, 12, 300, 2),
(16, 13, 230, 1),
(17, 6, 12000, 1),
(17, 15, 430, 2),
(18, 8, 7000, 2),
(18, 7, 3000, 2),
(19, 2, 18000.9, 1),
(20, 4, 4898.99, 1),
(21, 12, 300, 2),
(21, 8, 7000, 1),
(22, 10, 2300.56, 1),
(22, 14, 560, 2),
(23, 5, 17, 5),
(23, 5, 17, 3),
(24, 2, 18000.9, 1);
```

Usuarios

```
CREATE TABLE `usuarios` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `edad` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `usuario` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `contraseña` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `admin` varchar(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `usuarios` (`ID`, `nombre`, `edad`, `email`, `usuario`, `contraseña`, `status`, `admin`) VALUES
(0, 'ROBERTO VILLALOBOS ORTEGA', 22, 'robertoalcatel4010a@gmail.com', 'ROBERTO', '1234', '1', '1'),
(1, 'MALCOM EL DEL MEDIO', 19, 'malcom@gmail.com', 'MALCOM', '1234', '1', '0'),
(2, 'HALL WILKERSON', 45, 'qharrise_z588m@muyoc.com', 'JOSE', '1234', '1', '0'),
(3, 'JULIETA VENEGAS', 50, 'julieta@gmail.com', 'JULIETA', '1234', '0', '0'),
(4, 'GREGORIO PEREZ', 34, 'gregorio@outlook.com', 'GREGORIO', '5678', '1', '0'),
(5, 'MARIO ESPINOZA', 44, 'mario@outlook.com', 'MARIO', '1234', '1', '0'),
(6, 'LOIS WILKERSON', 56, 'lois@gmai.com', 'LOIS', '1234', '1', '0'),
(7, 'RAMON ANTONIO OLEA', 22, 'antoio@yahoo.com', 'RAMON', '1234', '1', '0'),
(8, 'AMANDA AZUCENA MEDINA', 21, 'aMANDA@yahoo.com', 'AMANDA', '1234', '1', '0'),
(9, 'OMAR MEDINA', 24, 'omar@gmail.com', 'OMAR', '1234', '1', '0'),
(10, 'DORA ORTEGA', 61, 'dora@gmail.com', 'DORA', '1234', '1', '0'),
(11, 'MARTIN SOLAMENTE', 20, 'martin@gmail.com', 'MARTIN', '1234', '1', '0');
```

Y necesito generar una consulta que me devuelva en orden ascendente los usuarios que han comprado mas cantidad de productos (ID_USUARIO, NOMBRE Y CANTIDAD DE PRODUCTOS COMPRADOS).
Hasta ahora llevo esto:

```
SELECT 
  id_venta, 
  id_usuario, 
  (
    SELECT sum(cantidad) 
    FROM detalle_ventas 
    WHERE detalle_ventas.id_venta = ventas.id_venta
  ) 
FROM ventas 
group by id_usuario
```

Pero me arroja valores incorrectos porque solo suma los primeros.

Comment: Por favor agrega unos datos de prueba para poder replicar el escenario y ayudarte

Comment: Listo amigo y gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para que sume la cantidad de productos hay que obtener la suma del campo cantidad de la tabla `detalle_ventas` para cada usuario, pero lo vamos a hacer relacionando las tablas con `inner join`.

```
SELECT u.ID, u.nombre, SUM(d.cantidad) AS TOTAL
FROM ventas v
INNER JOIN usuarios u ON u.ID = v.id_usuario
INNER JOIN detalle_ventas d ON d.id_venta = v.id_venta
GROUP BY u.ID, u.nombre ORDER BY TOTAL ASC;
```

Si no necesitas el nombre del usuario, solo el id, puedes simplificar aun más la `query` porque no necesitas el inner join con la tabla `usuarios`.

```
SELECT v.id_usuario, SUM(d.cantidad) AS TOTAL
FROM ventas v
INNER JOIN detalle_ventas d ON d.id_venta = v.id_venta
GROUP BY v.id_usuario ORDER BY TOTAL ASC;
```

Ejemplo con tus datos:

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE `ventas` (
  `id_venta` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_usuario` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fecha` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `ventas` (`id_venta`, `id_usuario`, `fecha`) VALUES
(1, 2, '2020-04-25 06:33:56'),
(2, 2, '2020-03-21 15:33:56'),
(3, 2, '2020-02-28 15:33:56'),
(4, 3, '2020-02-03 15:33:56'),
(5, 3, '2020-01-07 15:33:56'),
(6, 4, '2020-05-25 15:33:56'),
(7, 4, '2020-04-27 15:33:56'),
(8, 5, '2020-03-16 15:33:56'),
(9, 5, '2017-12-05 15:33:56'),
(10, 6, '2020-01-15 15:33:56'),
(11, 7, '2019-11-09 15:33:56'),
(12, 7, '2019-10-05 15:33:56'),
(13, 7, '2020-05-12 15:33:56'),
(14, 7, '2020-01-28 15:33:56'),
(15, 8, '2020-03-01 15:33:56'),
(16, 9, '2020-04-17 15:33:56'),
(17, 10, '2020-02-09 15:33:56'),
(18, 11, '2019-11-05 15:33:56'),
(19, 11, '2020-02-12 15:33:56'),
(20, 11, '2020-03-21 15:33:56'),
(21, 11, '2020-03-21 15:33:56'),
(22, 11, '2020-04-26 15:33:56'),
(23, 1, '2020-05-05 15:33:56'),
(24, 2, '2020-05-05 21:40:58');

CREATE TABLE `detalle_ventas` (
  `id_venta` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_producto` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `precio` double NOT NULL,
  `cantidad` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `detalle_ventas` (`id_venta`, `id_producto`, `precio`, `cantidad`) VALUES
(1, 2, 18000.9, 1),
(1, 4, 4898.99, 1),
(1, 1, 40000, 2),
(2, 3, 25000, 1),
(3, 4, 4898.99, 1),
(4, 6, 12000, 1),
(4, 8, 7000, 2),
(4, 11, 5400, 1),
(5, 14, 560, 1),
(6, 10, 2300.56, 3),
(6, 13, 230, 2),
(6, 12, 300, 1),
(7, 16, 17000, 1),
(8, 4, 4898.99, 3),
(8, 1, 40000, 3),
(8, 9, 1000, 1),
(8, 10, 2300.56, 2),
(8, 15, 430, 2),
(9, 3, 25000, 1),
(10, 3, 25000, 4),
(11, 6, 12000, 2),
(12, 1, 40000, 1),
(13, 14, 560, 1),
(14, 4, 4898.99, 5),
(15, 7, 3000, 3),
(15, 9, 1000, 1),
(15, 13, 230, 1),
(15, 11, 5400, 1),
(15, 12, 300, 2),
(16, 13, 230, 1),
(17, 6, 12000, 1),
(17, 15, 430, 2),
(18, 8, 7000, 2),
(18, 7, 3000, 2),
(19, 2, 18000.9, 1),
(20, 4, 4898.99, 1),
(21, 12, 300, 2),
(21, 8, 7000, 1),
(22, 10, 2300.56, 1),
(22, 14, 560, 2),
(23, 5, 17, 5),
(23, 5, 17, 3),
(24, 2, 18000.9, 1);

CREATE TABLE `usuarios` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `edad` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `usuario` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `contraseña` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `admin` varchar(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `usuarios` (`ID`, `nombre`, `edad`, `email`, `usuario`, `contraseña`, `status`, `admin`) VALUES
(0, 'ROBERTO VILLALOBOS ORTEGA', 22, 'robertoalcatel4010a@gmail.com', 'ROBERTO', '1234', '1', '1'),
(1, 'MALCOM EL DEL MEDIO', 19, 'malcom@gmail.com', 'MALCOM', '1234', '1', '0'),
(2, 'HALL WILKERSON', 45, 'qharrise_z588m@muyoc.com', 'JOSE', '1234', '1', '0'),
(3, 'JULIETA VENEGAS', 50, 'julieta@gmail.com', 'JULIETA', '1234', '0', '0'),
(4, 'GREGORIO PEREZ', 34, 'gregorio@outlook.com', 'GREGORIO', '5678', '1', '0'),
(5, 'MARIO ESPINOZA', 44, 'mario@outlook.com', 'MARIO', '1234', '1', '0'),
(6, 'LOIS WILKERSON', 56, 'lois@gmai.com', 'LOIS', '1234', '1', '0'),
(7, 'RAMON ANTONIO OLEA', 22, 'antoio@yahoo.com', 'RAMON', '1234', '1', '0'),
(8, 'AMANDA AZUCENA MEDINA', 21, 'aMANDA@yahoo.com', 'AMANDA', '1234', '1', '0'),
(9, 'OMAR MEDINA', 24, 'omar@gmail.com', 'OMAR', '1234', '1', '0'),
(10, 'DORA ORTEGA', 61, 'dora@gmail.com', 'DORA', '1234', '1', '0'),
(11, 'MARTIN SOLAMENTE', 20, 'martin@gmail.com', 'MARTIN', '1234', '1', '0');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT u.ID, u.nombre, SUM(d.cantidad) AS TOTAL
FROM ventas v
INNER JOIN usuarios u ON u.ID = v.id_usuario
INNER JOIN detalle_ventas d ON d.id_venta = v.id_venta
GROUP BY u.ID, u.nombre 
ORDER BY TOTAL ASC;

    | ID  | nombre                | TOTAL |
    | --- | --------------------- | ----- |
    | 9   | OMAR MEDINA           | 1     |
    | 10  | DORA ORTEGA           | 3     |
    | 6   | LOIS WILKERSON        | 4     |
    | 3   | JULIETA VENEGAS       | 5     |
    | 2   | HALL WILKERSON        | 7     |
    | 4   | GREGORIO PEREZ        | 7     |
    | 1   | MALCOM EL DEL MEDIO   | 8     |
    | 8   | AMANDA AZUCENA MEDINA | 8     |
    | 7   | RAMON ANTONIO OLEA    | 9     |
    | 5   | MARIO ESPINOZA        | 12    |
    | 11  | MARTIN SOLAMENTE      | 12    |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Para eso, debes unir las tres tablas mencionadas, y de todo ese conjunto debes agrupar el resultado como lo necesites.
(Edición): He cambiado la consulta agregando LEFT JOIN para que SIEMPRE reporte a todos los usuarios, tengan o no registros de VENTAS. También agrego una suma del campo cantidad, para diferenciar entre el NUMERO TOTAL DE VENTAS y la CANTIDAD DE PRODUCTOS VENDIDOS.

```
select u.ID, u.nombre, COUNT(*) as total_ventas, SUM(dv.cantidad) as cantidad_ventas
from usuarios u 
left join ventas v on u.ID = v.id_usuario
left join detalle_ventas dv on dv.id_venta = v.id_venta
group by u.ID, u.nombre
```

Para que funcione mejor, debes agregar las PRIMARY KEYS en las tablas. Así, con solo un GROUP BY u.ID podras acceder al resto de columnas de la tabla usuario.

Comment: La cantidad de cada producto en una venta puede ser 1 o más, con count(*) estás considerando que siempre es 1, no responde a lo solicitado.

Answer (score 1):

Ahí va mi propuesta:

```
SELECT ID ID_USUARIO,nombre NOMBRE,
  unidades CANTIDAD_DE_PRODUCTOS_COMPRADOS
  FROM (
    SELECT id_usuario ID,SUM(cantidad) unidades
      FROM ventas JOIN detalle_ventas USING(id_venta)
      GROUP BY 1  
  ) c1 JOIN usuarios USING(ID)
  ORDER BY unidades DESC;
```

Primero obtiene los artículos comprados por cada id y, después, ya se combina con los usuarios para obtener los nombres.